# Effects order in sound design

Tags: sound-effects-recording, reverb, fl-studio, production-mixing, delay

A producer told me that if want to use both a reverb and delay, i should put the delay first, so that its feedback does not clash with the decay of the reverb. Does the effects order you add to a sound in the mixer when producing matter?

Comment: I use FL studio

Comment: It rather depends on whether you want the return from the first send to be routed to the second, or bring them back down two independent returns. So your choices are, 1) to reverb the delay, 2) to delay the reverb, or 3) neither, run them independently. In the end it's your call, & whether you like the result or not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general the order matters a great deal. You'd generally want your chain to go something like Filters/EQ -> Compression -> Time effects (Reverb/Delay). EQ first because you usually wouldn't want to be compressing frequencies that aren't going to be there after passing through the EQ.

Specifically with Reverb / Delay that would probably come down to personal preference. But then honestly all of this does; there are good general guidelines.